# Align \text within align environment

Tags: align

Is it possible to align text snippets within an align environment?
I'd like to vertically align the symbols and the corresponding text.

If not, is there an alternative?

**Code:**

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{upgreek}

\begin{document}
\section{Variables and Parameters}
\begin{align*}
    &\Bar{p}=\Bar{\pi}^{\frac{1}{\left(\gamma\Gamma\right)}}\qquad\qquad\qquad\qquad\text{Text A},\\
    &\Theta=1+\epsilon\Bar{\Theta}\left(Z\right)+\epsilon^2\Tilde{\Theta}\qquad\text{Text B},\\
    &\pi=\Bar{\pi}\left(Z\right)+\epsilon^2\Gamma\Tilde{\pi}\qquad\qquad\text{Text C},\\
    &\mathbf{\Omega}=\mathbf{k}\left(f_{0}+\epsilon\beta\,y_{\textnormal{s}}\right)\qquad\text{Text D}
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Have a look if reading https://www.learnlatex.org/en/lesson-10#the-amsmath-package might help you

Comment: Here just replace `\qquad` (and multiples thereof) by `&&`. Align can do multiple alignment points, but you have to separate them by a `&`

Comment: Oh, thanks a lot!

Comment: Off-topic: There's absolutely no advantage to writing `\Bar` and `\Tilde` instead of the standard `\bar` and `\tilde`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a solution that employs an `alignat*` environment.

Do note that I also (a) replaced `\Bar{\pi}^{\frac{1}{\left(\gamma\Gamma\right)}}` with `\bar{\pi}^{1/(\gamma\Gamma)}` and (b) got rid of all `\left` and `\right` sizing directives (as they don't do anything useful, but do mess with proper horizontal spacing).

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath} % for 'alignat*' env. and '\text' macro

\begin{document}

\section{Variables and Parameters}

\begin{alignat*}{2}
    \bar{p} &= \bar{\pi}^{1/(\gamma\Gamma)}
    &\qquad& \text{Text A}, \\
    \Theta &= 1+\epsilon \bar{\Theta}(Z)+\epsilon^2 \tilde{\Theta}
    && \text{Text B}, \\
    \pi &= \bar{\pi}(Z)+\epsilon^2 \Gamma \tilde{\pi}
    && \text{Text C}, \\
    \mathbf{\Omega} &= \mathbf{k}(f_{0}+\epsilon\beta y_{\mathrm{s}})
    && \text{Text D}
\end{alignat*}

\end{document}
```